# density of distance between points in unit circles

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $a$ and $b$ be two points in the plane. Let's choose a point $c$ uniformly from the circle of radius $r$ with $a$ as center and choose a point $d$ uniformly from the circle of radius $r$  with $b$ as the centre of this circle. Let $X$ be the eucleadian distance between $c$ and $d$. What's the density function of $X$? Is it hard compute? 
P.S. I know how to do it when $a=b$.

Comment: MO is for math research questions. Is there a research angle to this question?

Comment: Yes Gerry, I want to compute average degree of nodes placed, roughly, in a grid where adjacency defined in terms of distance. Problem arises in sensor networks.

Comment: Do you mean the points are drawn from the interiors or from the boundaries?

Comment: What do you get when $a=b?$

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I meant to choose uniformly from the interior of circle.

When $a=b$, the expression doesn’t look pretty (not to me at least) but the argument/procedure is simple enough (It’s described in Tuckwell’s Applications of Probability Theory). Anyway here it is.
$f_X(x) = \frac{2x}{\pi r^2}( 2 \arccos(\frac{x}{2r}) - \frac{x}{r} \sqrt{ 1-{(\frac{x}{2r}) }^2}  )$.

Answer (score 2):

Empirically, the distribution appears approximately normal.
Below is the distribution for $10^6$ pairs of $c,d$-points,
$r=1$, $\| a - b \|=3$ (so the closet $X=\| c - d \|$ distance possible is $1$,
and the furthest distance possible is $5$.

---

[image: DistanceDistribution]

---

Comment: Seeing @DouglasZare's question, I assumed that "from the circle" and "in unit circles" mean from the interior of the circles (rather than on the circle boundaries).

Comment: This is interesting - it didn't occur to me to check it empirically. Can you think of a way to prove this hypothesis? Thanks.